# Extract part of string with bash script

Tags: bash

I am working on a bash script to automatically pull substrings and format the output. The input of the script is coming from other commands that are being piped to this script.

Example input:

> Session ID #112233: TicketID://111222333444 
> Name: John Smith 
> TimeStamp: xx:xx:xx:xx 
> Notes: "TicketID://111222333222 was replaced with this ticket."
> Session ID #112234: TicketID://111222333445 
> Name: John Smith 
> TimeStamp: xx:xx:xx:xx 
> Notes: "TicketID://111222333223 was replaced with this ticket."
> Session ID #112235: TicketID://111222333446 
> Name: John Smith 
> TimeStamp: xx:xx:xx:xx 
> Notes: "TicketID://111222333225 was replaced with this ticket."

The rest of the input may have another "TicketID" entry but I only want the ones that immediately follow a Session ID. The session ID itself is not important.

The end goal is to take all the Ticket ID's that came directly after "Session ID" and format them into one line like this:

> Ticket IDs: 111222333444,111222333445,111222333446

I tried using grep find the entry and TR to format the commas in-between but I was unable to figure out how to only get grep to return the TicketID instead of the entire line.

> grep -o "Session ID #.*: TicketID.*" | tr "/n" ','

This code almost works but it returns the entire matched line and all I need is the TicketID for that matched line.

Edit:

The -P option with grep cannot be used due to the environment it runs on.

Comment: Why you are trying with bash? You can use a language like python o nodejs. What is your attempt? Add more rows to your input example

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please always include the code of what you've tried and tell us what didn't work for you; see [ask]. As is, it looks l lot like you are asking us to do the work for you, without any effort from your end. Such questions tend to get downvoted and closed.

Comment: OP tagued bash, answered in bash

Comment: @JRichardsz I updated the post to be a little more clear sorry. I was trying this in bash since I thought it would be a bit more straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Like this, using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ printf '%s' 'Ticket IDs: '; sed -E 's@^Session ID.*TicketID://([0-9]+)+@\1@' file | paste -sd,
```

##### Output

```
Ticket IDs: 111222333444,111222333445,111222333446
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned the -P option cannot be used due to the environment.

Also matching just the TicketID would grab other instances where TicketID was used. I only need the instances where TicketID occurs after a Session ID. I updated my post to be a little more clear sorry about that.